# Comparing two vectors might be giving me an error

Tags: c++

So the idea behind this is that a user inputs a message, and the message gets translated to Morse code. It is a homework assignment I've been working on for over 8 hours today. It's also my first time seriously working with classes.

When run, I get only one error on line 64. The error I got makes no sense (and it's huuuuge so I don't want to include it unless asked). I suspect the issue is that the originalMessage vector and alphaCode vector are different vector types (string & char respectively).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Code
{
    private:
        vector<char> alphaCode;
        vector<string> morseCode;
        vector<string> originalMessage;
        vector<string> finalMessage;
    public:
        Code();
        void encoder(vector<string> input);
        void display();
};

Code::Code():alphaCode(), morseCode(28)
{
    //Building alphaCode
    for (char c='A'; c<='Z'; c++) alphaCode.push_back(c);
    alphaCode.push_back(' ');
    alphaCode.push_back('.');

    //Building morseCode
    morseCode[0] =".-";
    morseCode[1] ="-...";
    morseCode[2] ="-.-.";
    morseCode[3] ="-..";
    morseCode[4] =".";
    morseCode[5] ="..-.";
    morseCode[6] ="--.";
    morseCode[7] ="....";
    morseCode[8] ="..";
    morseCode[9] =".---";
    morseCode[10] ="-.-";
    morseCode[11] =".-..";
    morseCode[12] ="--";
    morseCode[13] ="-.";
    morseCode[14] ="---";
    morseCode[15] =".--.";
    morseCode[16] ="--.--";
    morseCode[17] =".-.";
    morseCode[18] ="...";
    morseCode[19] ="-";
    morseCode[20] ="..-";
    morseCode[21] ="...-";
    morseCode[22] =".--";
    morseCode[23] ="-..-";
    morseCode[24] ="-.--";
    morseCode[25] ="--..";
    morseCode[26] =".......";
    morseCode[27] ="x";
}

void Code::encoder(vector<string> input)
{
    originalMessage = input;
    for (int i = 0; i < originalMessage.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < alphaCode.size(); j++)
        {
            if (originalMessage[i] == alphaCode[j])
            {
                finalMessage.push_back(morseCode[j]);
                finalMessage.push_back(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}

void Code::display()
{
    for (int x; x < finalMessage.size(); x++) cout << finalMessage[x];
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

int main()
{
    vector<string> message;
    string temp;

    cout << "Input:" << endl;
    cin >> temp;
    message.push_back(temp);

    Code c1;
    c1.encoder(message);
    c1.display();

}
```

Comment: You got it figured out. What is the question? You are mixing types and comparing a whole string to a character. This doesn't make sense in c++.

Comment: Sorry, i'm still a newbie. Basically this is the assignment: http://cse.csusb.edu/murphy/cse202/hw2-2014.html

It's a bit hefty.

Comment: @SriniKumar -- FWIW, the better way to solve this problem is to use a `std::map` or lookup table.  Don't know why comp sci course would show you the worst way of solving this problem, by doing a linear search until you find the right code.

Comment: Which is line 64?    I'm not about to count the lines manually.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problem in your source code.
The first problem is message variable:

```
vector<string> message;
```

Could be changed to:

```
string message;
```

And change other parts of your code, based on this change.

The second problem backs to

```
for (int x; x < finalMessage.size(); x++) cout << finalMessage[x];
```

variable x is not initited, initite it or write a better loop like this:

```
for (const auto& x : finalMessage) cout << x;
```

Answer (score -2):

Please read the error message :

> prog.cpp:64:36: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'std::basic_string' and 'char')
>                if (originalMessage[i] == alphaCode[j])

`if (originalMessage[i] == alphaCode[j])`

`originalMessage` is a `vector<string>` while `alphaCode` is `vector<char>`

There is no way you can compare `char` with a `string`

You may want to change your function this way:

```
void Code::encoder(vector<string> input)
{
    originalMessage = input;
    for (int i = 0; i < originalMessage.size(); i++)
    {
        string i_string = originalMessage[i]; // get the string here
        for (int j = 0; j < alphaCode.size(); j++)
        {

            if (i_string.at(i) == alphaCode[j]) // get the char in string
            {
                finalMessage.push_back(morseCode[j]);
                finalMessage.push_back(" ");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT

Basically, we want to extract `char` information from the `string`

```
for (int i = 0; i < originalMessage.size(); i++) {
    string i_string = originalMessage[i];
    for (int j =0; i < i_string.size(); j++) {
       char at_j = i_string.at(j);
       // find this at_j in alphaCode
       // enncode  
    }
}
```

Comment: "There is no way you can compare char with a string". There are ways, but they make sense only in certain contexts, so there is no default way. Your "fix" is almost certainly wrong. "For `i`th string take `i`th character and find morse code mapping for it." doesn't sound too reasonable.

Comment: I tried it to out and there's an issue with the loop. Maybe I can create a char vector and pushback each element from originalMessage into this new vector?

Comment: @luk32, I did not provide a logical fix for the code, I have provided a work around to understand and get rid of the compilation error. If you notice, OP is trying to compare `if (originalMessage[i] == alphaCode[j])`.

Comment: @SriniKumar, `originalMessage` contains `string`s. Please iterate over the `vector` and get the `char` from every string and create the new data structure that you want to.